# read char from txt file is wrong

Tags: c, ascii

Hello guys please help me to understand something !

I have a txt file and I read different values. I'm doing it successfully but I have an ASCII too, ie. KS98B2

I am trying to read it and store it in a value. Could you please have a look at my code? The word "KS98B2" should be stored at the variable "name". So I declare it in the main as a char. Do you agree? 
Inside the "asc" function there is a putchar, and it is printed properly, I checked that, I receive KS98B2.

But, inside the asc function printf gives the value : 84122658
And inside main printf gives the value: 24

Yes, I put %d in printf and name is a char, but how is it possible that the variable is not the same ? How can I make it work? Please help me !

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

FILE *file;
char ch;


int asc(char eow, bool *eof) {
 int var = 0;
 
 while((ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {
  putchar(ch);
  
  if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) {
   var <<= 4;
   var += (ch - 'A' + 65);
  }
  else if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
   var <<= 4;
   var += (ch - '0');
  }  else if (ch == eow) {
   
   return var;  
  } else {
   puts("Incorrect syntax.\n");  
  }
 }
 putchar('\n');
 printf("Var inside asc %d\n", var);

}



int main() {
 char name;
 bool eof = false;
  
 if ((file = fopen("messages.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
  puts("WRONG FILE\n");
  return 1;
 }
 while(!feof(file)) {
  
  name= asc('\n', &eof);
 
  printf("Var main: %d\n", name);
 }
 fclose(file);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find that fgetc gets an int type rather than a char.

Comment: The return value is invalid when `Var inside asc...` is displayed .

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. So David, how do you propose that I store the value of this word in a variable and return it?

Comment: you want to do is not clear.

Comment: I want to read the word properly and store it in a variable. Maybe the implementation is wrong. For example, if it was an integer I would call this function :

int decimal(char eow) {
 int var = 0;
 
 while((ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {
 
  
  if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) { 
   var *= 10;
   var += (c - '0');
   
  } else if (ch == eow) { 
   return var;
  } else {
   puts("wrong syntax\n"); exit(1);
  }
 }
 
}

But how can I store properly a char?

Comment: 0) 4bit can be expressed are 16 different codes, but  A-Z0-9 is 36 species. 1) If you continue processing until EOF is encountered than the portion that contains the last character are discarded.

Comment: Do you want the conversion of 36 decimal? IE `A0`(36) => `360`(10)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE *file;
//char ch;//There is no need to be a global variable

int asc(char eow, bool *eof) {
    int var = 0;
    int ch;//Type in order to compare the EOF and value must be int

    while((ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF) {
        if(isupper(ch))
            var = var * 36 + (ch - 'A' + 10);
        else if(isdigit(ch))
            var = var * 36 + (ch - '0');
        else if (ch == eow)
            return var;  
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nIncorrect syntax.\n");  
        }
    }
    *eof = true;
    return var;
}

int main(void) {
    int name;//It must be int to receive the value of int
    bool eof = false;

    if ((file = fopen("messages.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        puts("WRONG FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(!feof(file)) {
        name= asc('\n', &eof);
        printf("Var main: %d\n", name);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
void putdecimal(int name) {
    int i=0;
    int var = name;
    int array[30];
    int cnt = 0;

    while(var){
        array[cnt++] = var % 36; 
        var /= 36;
    }

    for(i = cnt-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(array[i]<10)
            putchar(array[i] + '0');
        else
            putchar(array[i] - 10 + 'A');
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtol("KS98B2",NULL, 36)`

Comment: First I don't understand why you use 36, can you explain please this expression? 

Also, in ASCII the char A is decimal 65,  why do you use 10?

Last, in you code the integer that I print is  1256783438. 

However, the word I have in ASCII is KS98B2 which is decimal 75 83 57 56 66 50. Hence, what we print is wrong, right?

Comment: @aredhel_vlsi  1) 36 : 36 decimal. 2) +10 : `0123456789ABC...` position of `A` meant `10`. 3) `75 83 57 56 66 50` is 6 byte. But Int is a 32bit system it is expected that it 4byte. do you want `var <<= 8` ? Do you want to store the character to you why int? I think the problem will be solved if you pass received one character at a time character.

Comment: `KS98B2`(36) => `1256783438`(radix base 10)

Comment: `putdecimal(1256783438)` => `KS98B2`

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY for your replies, they really help. I have a question though. What if I would like to store the value of "name" in a char?

According to your way, I would need to convert again the int I printed to a char, which adds more effort. Do I need to store name it necessarily at an int? Can I use alternatively another function instead of fgetc? 

How could it be if I declare char name[20]; ?

Comment: @aredhel_vlsi I'm not sure you have what you want to do. I think you should use array of char  rather than of an int in order to preserve the character.

Comment: `char name[20];`.. `fgets(name, sizeof(name), file);`

Comment: Hi BLUEPIXY, thank you for your replies. Let me see if I understand correctly: I have inside main a loop :
main{
   

     while(!feof(f)) { 
         name = gasc('\n', &is_eof);

Comment: main{
   
     char name[20];
     while(!feof(f)) { 
         name = asc('\n', &is_eof);
     }

Where asc is defined:

char asc(char eow, bool *eof) {
    char v[20] ;
 char name[20];
 char c;
 
    while(c=fgets(name, sizeof(name), f)!=NULL) {
  
  puts(name);
  
  if (c == eow){
   
            return c;
   
  }
  
 }

 *eof = true;
 puts(".");
 return c;
}

However I receive error: error: incompatible types in assignment

Can you help? Escuse me for the bad fromatting but it doesn't allow me to answer to the first question, only comment.

Comment: @aredhel_vlsi Since the array is a constant and does not allow you to assign the return value from the function. You must be passed as an argument.

Comment: @aredhel_vlsi I have posted a sample as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example to store the read characters into an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

FILE *file;

char *gasc(int size, char buff[size], char eow){
    int i = 0, ch = 0;

    while(i < size - 1 && (ch=fgetc(file))!=EOF && ch != eow){
        if (isupper(ch) || isdigit(ch)){
            buff[i++] = ch;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nIncorrect syntax.\n");
        }
    }
    buff[i] = '\0';
    if(i == 0 && ch == EOF)
        return NULL;

    return buff;
}

int main(void) {
    char name[20];

    if ((file = fopen("messages.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        puts("WRONG FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //is_eof is no longer necessary to represent NULL return value of gasc instead of EOF.
    while(gasc(sizeof(name), name, '\n') != NULL) {
        printf("'%s'\n", name);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```